# How to retrieve recents video's comments for a Dailymotion account

Tags: api, video, http-get

I am asking me if it's possible to retrieve recents video's comments for a given Dailymotion account.

For example, i want to get all recents video's comments for a given account every 2 minuts.

I have found severals Dailymotion API but don't found thet way to to that.

I tknow it's possible to  read the list of a video‘s comments by issuing an HTTP GET to /video/{VIDEO_ID}/comments but do you know if it's possible to reteive all new comments for account's videos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://api.dailymotion.com/video/videoID/comments

will give you

{"page":1,"limit":10,"explicit":false,"has_more":false,"list":[{"id":"id","message":"wel done","owner":"id"},{"id":"id","message":"congrats","owner":"id"}]}

So, list has comments of video.Here there are 2 comments.